# why does it seem like two threads are accessing one lock in my code?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I'm trying to learn java multithreading, and this is a simple leetcode concurrency problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/print-foobar-alternately/). I came up with the following code, but I don't understand why it works. The problem says one thread call foo and one thread call bar, and it should print "foobar" n times.

```java
public class Foobar {
    int n;
    boolean hasFoo;
    Lock lock;
    Condition cond;
    public Foobar(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        hasFoo = false;
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        cond = lock.newCondition();
    }

    public void foo(Runnable printFoo) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            lock.lock();
            while (hasFoo) {
                cond.await();
            }
            printFoo.run();
            hasFoo = true;
            cond.signalAll();
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void bar(Runnable printBar) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            lock.lock();
            while (!hasFoo) {
                cond.await();
            }
            printBar.run();
            hasFoo = false;
            cond.signalAll();
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but I don't understand why. From my understanding, if the "bar" thread runs first and acquires the lock, it should wait and the "foo" thread will block in the `lock.lock();` line, but it turns out they both enter the locked part. Please enlighten me where I misunderstand lock in java.
Here is how I call these two methods.

```java
        Foobar f = new Foobar(10);
        Runnable rf = () -> {
            try {
                f.foo(() -> System.out.println("foo"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        Runnable rp = () -> {
            try {
                f.bar(() -> System.out.println("bar"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        Thread t1 = new Thread(rf, "foo-thread");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(rp, "bar-thread");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
```

Comment: Where are the two threads? Do they work on the same instance of `FooBar`? Because if they use separate instances they will also get separate locks (each instance has their own `Lock lock` field).

Comment: Show us also how you instantiate and run the threads.

Comment: Why do you need those conditions for? What does it do that just locking the lock itself does not achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the "bar" thread runs first and acquires the lock, it should wait ...

Wait for what? The "bar" thread is the first that acquired the lock, there is nothing to wait for. This thread will immediately proceed to the next statement, which is `cond.await();` where the lock will be released<sup>1</sup>, and the thread will go to sleep.

In the meanwhile, the "foo" thread can acquire the lock<sup>2</sup>, and print its message, and notify others that its job is done, which, subsequently, unlocks<sup>3</sup> the sleeping "bar".

> ... the "foo" thread will be blocked in the `lock.lock();`

Exactly.

> but it turns out they both enter the locked part.

No. One entered, another is waiting to enter. It's a simple lock - only one thread can acquire it at a time (it's like an advanced version of the `synchronized` statement).

---

> <sup>1</sup> The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant
>
> <sup>https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()</sup>

<sup>2</sup> Remember, it was blocked since it tried to acquire the lock shorty after the "bar" did it.

> If the lock is not available then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until the lock has been acquired.
>
> <sup>https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock()</sup>

<sup>3</sup> By signalling to all, which one of [the four methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()) to awake others.

> 2. Some other thread invokes the `signalAll()` method for this `Condition`;
>
> <sup>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()</sup>

Comment: What is the use case for these conditions? What do they do that cannot be achieved with just working with the lock itself (here, and also in general)?  (This is an honest question, I have never seen those used before)

Comment: Okay, the Javadoc explains that part: "Condition factors out the Object monitor methods (wait, notify and notifyAll) into distinct objects to *give the effect of having multiple wait-sets per object*, by combining them with the use of arbitrary Lock implementations. Where a Lock replaces the use of synchronized methods and statements, a Condition replaces the use of the Object monitor methods."  That does not seem to be needed here though.

Answer (score 2):

Her in `bar()`,  `Lock.lock()` takes the lock  but `Condition.await()` makes the thread waiting for and releases the lock too .

[`Condition.await()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await--) specifying (emphasis is mine) :

> Causes the current thread to wait until it is signalled or
>   interrupted.
>
> **The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released** and the
>   current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and
>   lies dormant until one of four things happens:

So supposing that `bar()` is executed before `foo()` :

```
public void bar(Runnable printBar) throws InterruptedException {
    // ...
    while (!hasFoo) { // true
      cond.await(); // release the lock and wait
    }
    // ...
}
```

So `bar()` waits but `foo()` goes further in its execution and prints `foo` :

```
public void foo(Runnable printFoo) throws InterruptedException {
  //...
  while (hasFoo) { // false
      cond.await();
  }
  // We print first so
}
```

Comment: "The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released"